# CGRectMake on Objective C will not load properly

Tags: xcode, webview, objective-c-2.0

I have one web view and I am trying to load a dynamic page from my site in that code.

`myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 768.0f, 1024.0f)];`

but it does not load whole page. it starts page from 1/3 of the image i.e. from 200 pixel or something. Does anyone have any idea what may be wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame you give to the web view specifies its size, not its content's size. Since the screen isn't 768 x 1024 pixels, only part of the web view is visible. You could try the web view's `scalesPagesToFit` property, which will cause the web view to zoom out so that the entire page is visible.

```
myWebView.scalesPagesToFit = YES;
```

Comment: hi, this does not work. It does not scale my page. The problem here is not zoom. My 1/3 page is cut and web view start showing it from like 200 pixels or so.

Comment: i forgot to mention. I am doing this for iPad not for iPhone

Comment: It got solved by ipad orientation capture. Thanks for the help